# Auto Hide notification message in asp.net

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, custom-controls

I need to make custom control that is auto hided when it being filled in server side, Is possible using jquery ?

Comment: Can You please explain what You want to accomplish more specifically?

Comment: http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/02/show-jquery-notification-pop-up-message.html

Comment: @patrykf I need to generate error message that is hided automaticlley

Comment: the msg should be shown and hidden when what ? please be explain more so we can help.. is related to some time span, or on mouse over or what ?

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh By automatically You mean: It disappears after some seconds or it dissapear after your server returns some error?

Comment: @patrykf It disappears after few seconds

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh yes, this is possible in jquery and in the second comment (from Dylan) it is explained how to achieve this.